# How to minimize all other panels except the one I want to keep open?

Tags: macos

My requirement is to be able to drag a folder from my desktop to my Terminal app. To do this, I must minimize all other panels except the Terminal.

The beginning status:

[image]

The result:

[image]

So, if I minimize the panels one by one, it can be very time consuming. Is there a quicker way to achieve this?

Comment: Somewhere under "Window" there should be a button that says "Hide Others" (it might also be under "File") - I'm not positive, I'm not at my computer right now.

Comment: @NoahL, I did not find that.

Comment: It's under the application menu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the active application, at the bottom of the application menu itself, you should have a number of options you can use, namely: Hide *Application Name*; Hide Others; and, Show All.

On an English keyboard you can use the following shortcuts:

- <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to Hide *Application Name*
- <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to Hide Others

I'm not sure if it will be the same for you.

Regardless, using the example in your question, the simplest workflow to achieve what you want would be:

- Open Terminal (to make Terminal the active app)
- In the menu bar go to Terminal > Hide Others (to hide everything else, including the Finder's open windows)
- Drag folder over to Terminal

By doing the first two steps you're basically making the Desktop visible, which is where your folder is, while also keeping the Terminal app open.

Of course, you should also be able to do the first two via keyboard shortcuts of some kind.

**NOTE:** - Once you're done, you can make all the Finder windows visible again simply by returning to the Finder. This works because you didn't actually minimise the windows to begin with.

Answer (score 4):

Monomeeth's answer is absolutely correct, but in the interest of providing alternatives, I have a functionally similar requirement fairly regularly and my approach is:

1. Press F11/whatever shortcut you have defined for 'Show desktop'
2. Grab the required file from the desktop with the mouse (click and hold)
3. Press F11/shortcut for 'show desktop' again.
4. Drop grabbed file into the destination window.

For me, this has the advantage of leaving any other windows/apps visible after I've finished grabbing the file I need.